# Extrapolation from data plotted using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 10 values of x and y in my file.

Is there any way that I can extrapolate the graph ie make it into a continous function and increasing its range for other x-values in matplotlib ??

I would even be thankful if anyone can tell me if there is any other software that I can use. I basically want that these 10 values get approximated to a continous function so that I can know the y-value at some random x point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make scipy.interpolate give an extrapolated result beyond the input range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

below i use *Scipy*, but the *same* functions (*polyval* and *polyfit*) are also in *NumPy*; NumPy is a Matplotlib dependency so you can import those two functions from there if you don't have SciPy installed.

```
import numpy as NP
from scipy import polyval, polyfit
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT

n=10   # 10 data points
# make up some data
x = NP.linspace(0, 1, n)
y = 7*x**2 - 5*x + 3
# add some noise 
noise = NP.random.normal(.5, .3, 10)
y += noise

# the shape of the data suggests a 2d polynomial, so begin there
# a, b, c are the polynomial coefficients: ax^2 + bx + c
a, b, c = polyfit(x, y, 2)
y_pred = polyval([a, b, c], x)    # y_pred refers to predicted values of y

# how good is the fit?
# calculate MSE:
MSE = NP.sqrt( NP.sum((y_pred-y)**2)/10 )
# MSE = .2

# now use the model polynomial to generate y values based on x values outside 
# the range of the original data:
x_out = NP.linspace(0, 2, 20)   # choose 20 points, 10 in, 10 outside original range
y_pred = polyval([a, b, c], x_out)

# now plot the original data points and the polynomial fit through them
fig = PLT.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(x, y, 'g.', x_out, y_pred, 'b-' )

PLT.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `SciPy` (Scientific Python) you can try `scipy.interp1d`. See the [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) for an example.

Otherwise, any decent spreadsheet software should be able to do spline interpolation and give you a nice smooth graph.

Beware of *extrapolation*, though. If you don't have a good model for your data you might get completely unrelated data when extrapolating outside your input range.

Example (EDIT):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# the available data points
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [10, 20, 30]

# return a function f, such that f(x) is the interpolated value at 'x'
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
```

You can now compute the function `f(x)` at any point `x`. For example `print f(2.5)` will return the interpolated value for x=2.5.