# Logarithmic interpolation in python

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Using `numpy.interp` I am able to compute the one-dimensional piecewise linear interpolant to a function with given values at discrete data-points.

Is it a similar function to return me the logarithmic interpolation?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly you mean by 'logarithmic interpolation'. Could you give some example input/output?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the past, I've just wrapped the normal interpolation to do it in log-space, i.e.

```
def log_interp(zz, xx, yy):
    logz = np.log10(zz)
    logx = np.log10(xx)
    logy = np.log10(yy)
    return np.power(10.0, np.interp(logz, logx, logy))
```

Personally, I much prefer the [scipy interpolation functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/interpolate.html#module-scipy.interpolate) (as @mylesgallagher mentions), for example:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate

def log_interp1d(xx, yy, kind='linear'):
    logx = np.log10(xx)
    logy = np.log10(yy)
    lin_interp = sp.interpolate.interp1d(logx, logy, kind=kind)
    log_interp = lambda zz: np.power(10.0, lin_interp(np.log10(zz)))
    return log_interp
```

Then you can just call this as a function on an arbitrary value.

Comment: I have tried this metod but it cannot interpolate values out of the range used in for interpolating. Do you know a way for estimating new values?

Comment: @LuisGonzález scipy doesn't have extensive support for extrapolation, but check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166155/230468, NOTE: extrapolation, especially with splines, can result in surprising behavior (e.g. the curve can 'turn' sharply outside of the input range).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have some discrete data that you want to get a smooth set of values that would arise in between the values you have.  I am assuming you don't want an equation of a log function that approximates the data.

Unfortunately numpy does not have anything outside of the linear piecewise interpolation, however if you look into using [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) it does have a more powerful interpolation function. See [SciPy's interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/interpolate.html#module-scipy.interpolate) documentation for more detail.

It includes more complex interpolations like 'cubic' interpolations which will give you very smooth approximations, but it won't be a logarithm and it won't give you an equation.

If you want an equation what you are looking for is a regression technique not interpolation, but I don't think you are.