# How to draw another set of axis on the same figure using matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want my mathplotlib figure to have another set of axis/lines. Currently I do as follows:

```
plt.plot([0,eigenVectors[0][0]],[0,eigenVectors[1][0]],color='k',marker='o')
plt.plot([0,eigenVectors[0][1]],[0,eigenVectors[1][1]],color='k',marker='o')
```

where eigenVector is a 2d matrix and I am just trying to draw lines passing through the eigenvectors and the origin. However, as it is evident, I am drawing two line segments not lines. I wish to draw two lines passing through origin and the eigenvectors. Is there a way to say that draw a line (not a line segment) passing through two points?

My current plot looks like this:

[image]

PS: I am trying to implement PCA.

Comment: Just to confirm, that I got it right: You would like to basically replace the two `plt.plot` calls by one and get the same line, right?

Comment: Each plt.plot call draws a line segment, I want to replace each with something that draws a line.

Comment: So you would like to get rid of the entire 2 calls to `plt.plot` and replace it with something that just draws a line? Even though `plt.plot` does this?

Comment: plt.plot is drawing a line segment, not a line.

Comment: Why? Why isn't a long line segment good enough?

Answer (score 0):

You could extrapolate linearly to some large values and use them to plot the lines. Then limit the `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` to some sensible value. For more information on the extrapolation, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range).

Comment: This draws a line segment between the two points given. I want a line, not a line segment. By line I mean it should extend indefinitely and not just confine itself between the two points.