# scipy PchipInterpolator implementation problems

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to implement PchipInterpolator based on the link:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html

The code I am using is:

```
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
set_interp  =   scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator( x, y, extrapolate=True )
```

I get the error as:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extrapolate'
```

So, obviously I am implementing it the wrong way. I have tried numerous other ways to implement extrapolate but it fails.

Comment: See this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? It is a pure python function, so you could use ipython or inspect to look at the constructor and its arguments for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PchipInterpolator` was refactored in version 0.14, and that's when it has grown the `extrapolate` keyword.

Compare the docs for the version 0.13: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html

and version 0.14: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html

(disclaimer: I was involved in that refactor)

Scipy 0.13 is quite old by now, best consider upgrading.

More recent scipy versions are slightly better in terms of consistency in `interpolate`. For one, all polynomial-based interpolators (PPoly, BPoly, Pchip and Akima) have the `extrapolate` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
set_interp  =   interpolate.PchipInterpolator( x, y, extrapolate=True )
```

I got no error

Comment: I still get the same error. My version:scipy.version.version
Out[6]: '0.13.2'. What version are you using

Comment: @user1243255 i didnt get error , see the link i commented under your question , maybe its solve your problem