# Completing a curve using a function

Tags: python, plot, model

I have developed a model in Python to simulate something physical. This model outputs angular velocity over a distance range.  For various reasons the model does not give results for small distance values, but it has been suggested to me that I complete the curve using a function which we believe approximates the small distance regime.

My question is, how can I actually implement this?  It is not obvious to me how to tie together the curve that results from the model with the known analytic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a piecewise function. For example if you know that your angular velocity function is valid for `r > 10`, then you could do something like

```
def angular_velocity(r):
    if r > 10:
        your_analytical_function(r)
    else:
        some_alternative_for_small_distance(r)
```

If your question is more of how to determine an equation for small ranges, then that would really depend on your data and model. There are ways you can [extrapolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range) your data, but in general you should be [wary of extrapolation](https://xkcd.com/605/).