# Python scipy.interpolate.interp1d not working with large float values

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`to plot longitude and latitude values to x-coordinate and y-coordinate pixels of a map image. I have sample values:

```
y = [0, 256, 512, 768, 1024, 1280, 1536] 
lat = [615436414755, 615226949459, 615017342897, 614807595000, 614597705702, 614387674936, 614177502635] 
x = [0, 256, 512, 768, 1024, 1280, 1536, 1792, 2048, 2304] 
lon = [235986328125, 236425781250, 236865234375, 237304687500, 237744140625, 238183593750, 238623046875, 239062500000, 239501953125, 239941406250]
```

when I pass to the function like this:

```
xInterpolation = interp1d(xDegree, xPixel)
    yInterpolation = interp1d(yDegree, yPixel)

    return (int(xInterpolation(lon)),int(yInterpolation(lat)))
```

I get value error:

> ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation " ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.

No matter what value I try, it throws value error, I have even tried giving the same lat or lon values that are in the input list but that didn't work either. Does anybody know whats happening here? Or if I am using the wrong Interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

From `interp1d` [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

> bounds_error : bool, optional If True, a ValueError is raised any time
>   interpolation is attempted on a value outside of the range of x (where
>   extrapolation is necessary). If False, out of bounds values are
>   assigned fill_value. By default, an error is raised.

So, some of yours interpolated data is above interpolation bound. You are trying to extrapolate, not interpolate.

When you use interpolation like

`xInterpolation = interp1d(xDegree, xPixel)
 xInterpolation(lon)`

all values from `lon` must belong to the interval `[xDegree.min, xDegree.max]`.

So, you need to correct your data for interpolation or use [extrapolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range).

Comment: No, it is not above interpolation bound. I have double checked that and also mentioned this piece of information in the question.

Comment: @Omayr well, then, can you give samples for all arrays from your question?