# Extrapolating with a single data point

Tags: python, numpy, extrapolation

Is there an function for extrapolating in numpy?

I tried using the interp but of course that interpolates between the range of my values and not outside the range of values.

So for example i have my x-values between 1 and 8, inclusive, and for each x-value, i have its corresponding y-value and I want to find the y-value when my x-value is 0

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,8,1)
y = np.array((10,20,30,40,50,60,70))
np.interp(0,x,y)
```

Is there a function like the interp??

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745496/2666859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scipy.interpolate.interp1d allows extrapolation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.arange(1,8,1)
y = np.array((10,20,30,40,50,60,70))
interpolate.interp1d(x, y, fill_value='extrapolate')
```

hope this answers your question