# numpy.digitize / numpy.searchsorted: recycle indices without IndexError

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have vectorized an array `values` of test values, whose locations I would like to find in an array of `bins`. `numpy` allows for this using `np.digitize` or `np.searchsorted`:

```
import numpy as np
values=np.arange(-5.1,20.9,0.5)
bins=np.arange(10)

indices=np.digitize(values,bins)
indices2=np.searchsorted(bins,values)
assert((indices==indices2).all()), 'NB np.digitize and np.searchsorted argument orders are reversed'
```

It seems obvious, but I now wish to use my nice shiny vector array `indices`, but the following throws an `IndexError` because `np.digitize` and `np.searchsorted` (helpfully) set out-of-bounds inputs to `0` or `len(bins)`:

```
print bins[indices] # -> IndexError
```

Since *the whole point was to keep everything vectorized*, what is the best way to trap the IndexError without a for-loop and hence assign the output of `bins[indices]` to another array for onward calculation? (A clip value is available on request :) )

Should I use a custom mapping function or lambda? (along the lines of [How to make scipy.interpolate give an extrapolated result beyond the input range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range) - except I don't want to interpolate an exact array)

Thanks as ever for all help

**Update:**

I could actually - in my case - achieve the desired onward behaviour with:

```
indices[indices==len(bins)]=len(bins)-1
print bins[indices]
```

But this does lose some information* and the most general, best-practice route - which is what I am after - is not clear to me.

*That's because I would no longer be able to distinguish between acceptable indices and those that were out-of-bounds.

Comment: What about producing `bins` as length `n_bins` and use `indices=np.digitize(values, bins[:n_bins-1])` - in this case you have an extra bin for your outliers?

Comment: Could you list out how would you lose out information with the Update section code?

Comment: @Divakar Done..!