# How to set upper and lower bound on B-Spline result to get a reasonable interpolation

Tags: python, math, interpolation

I have interpolation function:

```
from scipy import interpolate
def f(x):
  x_points = [38508,38510,38512]
  y_points = [0.249267578125,0.181396484375,0.1912841796875]

  tck = interpolate.splrep(x_points, y_points,k=2,xb=38508,xe=38512)
  return interpolate.splev(x, tck)
```

when i evaluate `f(38503)` output is `0.75` which is nothing like y_points.

Any suggestion on how to decrease this error using this or other interpolation methods?

Comment: That's not interpolation, it's extrapolation (the point you are asking for is outside of bounds of the training set).  What "error" are you trying t decrease?  This is a perfectly reasonable curve-fitting result if you consider the curve presented by the 3 input points.

Comment: fyi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RishiG pointed out in the comments, what you want to do is extrapolation.

The [object oriented approach](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) has an extra parameter for this: `ext`.

```
from scipy import interpolate

def f(x):
    x_points = [38508, 38510, 38512]
    y_points = [0.249267578125, 0.181396484375, 0.1912841796875]

    tck = interpolate.splrep(x_points, y_points,k=2,xb=38508,xe=38512)
    return interpolate.splev(x, tck)

def g(x):
    x_points = [38508, 38510, 38512]
    y_points = [0.249267578125, 0.181396484375, 0.1912841796875]

    spl = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x_points, y_points, k=2, ext=3)

    return spl(x)

if __name__=='__main__':

    print(f(38503))
    print(g(38503))
```

Output:

```
0.7591400146484374
0.249267578125
```

Edit:

[This similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329) might also be interesting.