# Is there a function or a piece of code that will make it so turret can predict where will target be and shoot at the place? (Linear Prediction)

Tags: python, game-physics, prediction, predict, bullet

I'm making a game with turrets and bots included and I wanted to make some `SmartAim()` function that will make them "smarter" and they will predict the position and shoot so they will *almost* never miss.

---

I tried to search and code my own program but there is still one thing missing: the bullet and target SPEED. i am moving bullets trough `Sin()` and `Cos()` but i never managed to get it right

Comment: This feels like a math question rather than a programming one. But seeing that you posted this to StackOverflow, I'd recommend including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so this question doesn't get flagged or closed for not having enough information.

Comment: It might be better to ask this question over at Software Engineering:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make scipy.interpolate give an extrapolated result beyond the input range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range)