# Fit nonlinear regression pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, non-linear-regression

I have a dataset [Coronavirus cases per day with dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU58j.png)
And then I made this plot, Cases vs Days, which is a curved line. [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BLig.png)

I would like to fit a curved line that predicts future cases. But how to do that? I'm new and I'm used to linear regression. Fitting a linear regression line is much simpler. Is there any simple way to fit a curved line too? I tried youtube but there aren't many videos on this.
And how can I print predicted cases for the next 10 days?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post code from what you've tried already?

Comment: @SilverNitrateIon I only preprocessed the dataset. I haven't tried any code yet. I saw the sklearn svr documentation. But couldn't understand the syntax. I thought there might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: You can try a gaussian process regression https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html, though looking at the newer comments it may not be any simpler syntax than SVR.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to fit higher order polynomials, you are typically looking either for [spline fitting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) or [polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html). Spline fitting will draw a fit using a specified number of line segments, where as polyfit will fit a polynomial of specified order to the system given.

Example from the docs for spline fitting:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True)
y = np.cos(-x**2/9.0)
f = interp1d(x, y)
```

From the docs for polyfit

```py
x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
```

Polyfit has the advantage of allowing you to extrapolate rather easily by calling the generated polyfit function on the value, whereas spline fits require more advanced extrapolation methods, [as per this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range).

Comment: @ALollz I completely agree, you would want to use something like a SIR model (for instance), however, the poster asked for poly-fitting/curve fitting measures.