# Logarithmic Regression of Data in Python

Tags: python, plot, regression

I'm having some trouble with getting my code to work and plot the results I want to. I suspect it is a very simple task and probably was answered here already but none of the Q&As on here seem to work for me.

I have very simple data x = [1,2,3] and y1 = [802, 1126, 1364] and y2 = [246, 368, 388]
I want to create a logarithmic trend and an extrapolation for x = [4:25]. I was able to create a linear or exponential or cubic trend but no log regression. It should look like this

[image]

I get it to work in Excel but I need a Python Plot for this

Thank you guys a lot for any help

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import splrep, splev


# Plot data
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100)
y1 = [0, 802, 1126, 1364]
y2 = [0, 246.5 , 368.9, 388.3]
x = [0, 1,2,3]

coeffs1 = np.polyfit(np.log(x), y1, 1)
coeffs2 = np.polyfit(np.log(x), y2, 1)

#Add trendline (spline)
trend1 = splrep(x, y1, k=2)
trend2 = splrep(x, y2, k=2)

x_new = np.linspace(min(x), max(x) + 20, num=100)
y1_new = splev(x_new, trend1)
y2_new = splev(x_new, trend2)

plt.plot(x, y1, 'ro', label='y1', markersize=5)
#plt.plot(x,trendpoly1(x),trendline1, 'r-', label=trendlabel1, linewidth=1)
plt.plot(x_new, y1_new, label='Spline extrapolation')


plt.plot(x, y2, 'bx', label='y2', markersize=5)
#plt.plot(x,trendpoly2(x),trendline2, 'b--', label=trendlabel2, linewidth=1)
plt.plot(x_new, y2_new, label='Spline extrapolation')
```

Comment: What have you tried in Python ?

Comment: @Nathan Added my Code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, may I know what version of Scipy you are using? Because the official documentation of scipy does not have `splrev` and `splev` attributes in `scipy.optimize`, but these two attributes are existed in `scipy.interpolate`.
[the link of scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)

What I am saying now is assuming that the two attributes that you are using now are the same as what existed in `scipy.interpolate`. According to the documentation, these two attributes are used in interpolation rather than extrapolation. This may help you to figure out how to extrapolate by using interpolation module. [The question asked by other before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745329/how-to-make-scipy-interpolate-give-an-extrapolated-result-beyond-the-input-range)